# Add to cart using Shopify ajax api in simple php code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, shopify

Trying to add to cart functionality in my custom php code using `shopify` ajax api. My code is below for which getting error code 401.

Anybody can give me example of how use the Shopify ajax apis or solve problem in code below in php code.

CODE:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
    use phpish\shopify;

    require __DIR__.'conf.php';

    $shopify = shopify\client(SHOPIFY_SHOP, SHOPIFY_APP_API_KEY, SHOPIFY_APP_PASSWORD, true);

    try
    {
        $add = $shopify('POST /cart/add.js',array(), array
        (
            'cart' => array
            (
                "quantity" => 2,
                "id" => 3908511558
            )
        ));
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($add);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
    catch(shopify\ApiException $e)
    {
        echo $e;
        echo "<pre>";
        print_R($e->getRequest());
        print_R($e->getResponse());
        echo "</pre>";
    }
    catch(shopify\CurlException $e)
    {
        echo $e;
        echo "<pre>";
        print_R($e->getRequest());
        print_R($e->getResponse());
        echo "</pre>";
    }
?>
```

ERROR:

```
phpish\shopify\ApiException: [401] Unauthorized
```

Comment: Code seems okay. Check your API credentials?

Comment: `cart/add.js` only work in shopify store environment, not external pages.

Comment: API credentials are correct. please give me example of usage of this api in php.

Comment: `cart/add.js` not belong to the [shopify api](https://docs.shopify.com/api)

Comment: Thanks miglio for helping me and i am also try jquery ajax api of shopify for add to cart but when i run this api in my localhost then shopify gives me 401 error for authentication and ask me to replace code in my shopify store or enable to Your CROS. So please if you have example of jquery ajax api please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending wrong parameters to the api. Try :

```
shopify\client(STORE_NAME, SHOPIFY_APP_API_KEY, ACCESS_TOKEN);
```

in place of :

```
$shopify = shopify\client(SHOPIFY_SHOP, SHOPIFY_APP_API_KEY, SHOPIFY_APP_PASSWORD, true);
```

Rest of the code seems correct.